# How to get all file path from C:/ drive?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, filesystems

I'm trying to retrieve all files from the root (C:/) in C++

First of all, I retrieve all logical drives in the computer, then I use the std::filesystem library (specifically the **recursive_directory_iterator** function in order to loop in directories)

```
    DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
    char szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize, szLogicalDrives);

    if (dwResult > 0 && dwResult <= MAX_PATH)
    {
        char* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives;
        while (*szSingleDrive)
        {
            szSingleDrive[strlen(szSingleDrive) - 1] = 0;
            printf(szSingleDrive);
            for (fs::directory_entry p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(szSingleDrive))
            {

                string filePath = p.path().string();
                // Vérification du type de l'objet
                if (fs::is_regular_file(p.path()))
                {

                    cout << filePath << endl;


                }

            // get the next drive
            szSingleDrive += strlen(szSingleDrive) + 1;
        }
      }
    }
```

However, the output I get is the path of my project.
Eg : **C:x64\Debug\myProject.exe**

Desired output : **C:\Users, C:\Windows, C:\Program Files...**

Comment: Ask yourself what this line (`szSingleDrive[strlen(szSingleDrive) - 1] = 0;`) is doing, and why it is there.

Comment: The `\ ` after C: is not there for decoration. Also, why are you comparing a bool to `std::string::npos`?

Comment: `if (fs::is_regular_file(p.path()) == string::npos)` should be `if (fs::is_regular_file(p.path()))` or simpler `if (p.is_regular_file())`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes my bad, I edited the STF code before I post to remove unnecessary information. This line was for : **if (fs::is_regular_file(p.path()) && filePath.find(exclPath.string()) == string::npos)** where exclPath = C:\\Windows, in order to exclude this path

Comment: @Botje yay, I tried with "C:\\" but Filesystem throw an error : Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBE0384ED9 in program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x000000AE6953F1F0. Did you ever try to run recusive_driectory function in root path ?

Comment: You might need to create the `recursive_directory_iterator` with the `skip_permission_denied` option enabled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes thanks, I launched VS in Admin + I disabled Windows defender and it works better now. However I still get "Access denied", I wil try with skip_permission_denied as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the issue I had to launch VS 2019 in admin (or launch the `.exe` in admin) + disable Windows Defender.

To avoid UAC exception, I also added `skip_permission_denied` in filesystem option.

However, my program still encounter `"Sharing Violation error"`